# Can I optimize this Word Mover's Distance look-up function?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, dask, gensim, wmd

I am trying to measure the Word Mover's Distance between a lot of texts using Gensim's Word2Vec tools in Python. I am comparing each text with all other texts, so I first use itertools to create pairwise combinations like `[1,2,3] -> [(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)]`. For memory's sake, I don't do the combinations by having all texts repeated in a big dataframe, but instead make a reference dataframe `combinations` with indices of the texts, which looks like:

```
    0   1
0   0   1
1   0   2
2   0   3
```

And then in the comparison function I use these indices to look up the text in the original dataframe. The solution works fine, but I am wondering whether I would be able to it with big datasets. For instance I have a 300.000 row dataset of texts, which gives me about a 100 year's worth of computation on my laptop:

```
C2​(300000) = 300000​! / (2!(300000−2))!
           = 300000⋅299999​ / 2 * 1
           = 44999850000 combinations
```

Is there any way this could be optimized better?

My code right now:

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from gensim.corpora.wikicorpus import WikiCorpus

def get_distance(row):
    try: 
        sent1 = df.loc[row[0], 'text'].split()
        sent2 = df.loc[row[1], 'text'].split()
        return model.wv.wmdistance(sent1, sent2)  # Compute WMD
    except Exception as e:
        return np.nan

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# I then set up the gensim model, let me know if you need that bit of code too.

# Make pairwise combination of all indices
combinations = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(df.index, 2))

# To dask df and apply function
dcombinations = dd.from_pandas(combinations, npartitions= 2 * multiprocessing.cpu_count())
dcombinations['distance'] = dcombinations.apply(get_distance, axis=1)
with ProgressBar():
    combinations = dcombinations.compute()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use [wmd-relax](https://github.com/src-d/wmd-relax) for performance improvement. However, you'll first have to convert your model to spaCy and use the SimilarityHook as described on their webpage:

```
import spacy
import wmd

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
nlp.add_pipe(wmd.WMD.SpacySimilarityHook(nlp), last=True)
doc1 = nlp("Politician speaks to the media in Illinois.")
doc2 = nlp("The president greets the press in Chicago.")
print(doc1.similarity(doc2))
```